# Unwanted lines when using the "KNIFE" tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

While using the "Knife" tool in overlapping letters, it shows unwanted lines on the cut path after I'm finished cutting the object and sending it to the back or front.

I'm facing this issue only when I send the cut object to front or back after I'm done cutting the object. If I don't send it to the back or front then these lines are not shown, which is what I want.

[image]

Comment: There is a flaw in th way the image from vector drawing tools in general is being generated. You should therefore always strive to cut a copy, because pieces have to overlap/underlip otherwise you get these things. They are by the way called conflation artifacts. Masking does not really help ultimately same problem.

Comment: This may be a better explanation of what im [trying to say](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060)

Comment: What do you mean by "always strive to cut a copy? Will that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes if your object isnt outlined

Comment: Kindly elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **Knife Tool** make a **Transparency Mask**

- With the **Direct Selection Tool** select the paths that overlays the Q
- **Menu Edit** > **Copy**
- **Menu Edit** > **Past in Front**
- Select the right border points, **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**
- Select the left border points, **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**

[image]

- Fill the new shape 100% Black
- Select it together with the Q
- **Transparency Panel** > **Make Mask** > Uncheck Clip

[image: Mask]

[image: animation]

Comment: I appreciate your posting of reply but I really don't get it..it seems too complicated.

Comment: The advantage to @Danielillo's answer is that it leaves your original elements untouched (it is a non-destructive workflow) such that easy editing of shapes is still within your reach - they remain whole entities.
The transparency mask over the top tells illustrator to selectively "clip" display of that area, and the mask form is also live editable. Moreover, the transparency mask works using the value of the colour as the alpha - so you can use gradients in a transparency mask if you wish to get complex effects: it's a really good technique to know.