# Is there a graph paper like drawing software?

Tags: vector, drawing

I want to draw some vectors in a software that creates grids and i simply click on dots and create lines and shapes (exactly like drawing on graph paper but on computer). Something like this image:

[image]

I already tested Illustrator (too complicated) and Inkscape (too weird!)

Edit: for example In following image, I want to simply delete those lines, for this in both software i should manually create points and delete part of line between to point (correct me if i'm wrong).
I just want to click on lines and it delete inner part.

[image]

Comment: Hi Amir and welcome to the site. Illustrator and Inkscape are the two applications that I (and I think many others) would recommend. Can you explain *why* you think they are to complicated and weird?

Comment: There's nothing complicated/weird about applying a simple grid in either Illustrator or Inkscape, and employing snap to grid.  Both can easily do  exactly what you want, and are specifically designed for vector work such as your example, and yet you discount them?!

Comment: @Wolff please check edited question.

Comment: You have already listed to two best tools for the task. The time spent writing this question could have been spent watching a couple of tutorials to get yourself up and running.

Comment: Illustrator's Shape Builder kills the unwanted lines. Click and hold Alt key at the same time. Learn it!

Comment: There's no need to delete anything if you make the shapes closed paths. Then you could just fill them with white to hide the lines below. See [example in Inkscape](https://imgur.com/a/5XI0Dla). The same is possible in Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and kindness(!), It's just an example, I already familiar with cad programs like Catia and Autocad, in both of them it's very easy to do this. But i want to work with a graphic software, That's why i need a simple and fast software.

Comment: Illustrator and Inkscape are simple and fast. In the example I made, the objects were selected, and the fill changed to white in an instant. Before discounting software, take some time to learn it and the principles of how it works.

Comment: How much simpler do you need to be? thing is there arent many choices out there that will be any simpler. Yeah shapebuilder does what you want. Generally illustrator has better gridnap. And many easier software dont have snapping at all.

Comment: https://sketchtoy.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Before you embark on this road it *may* be good to know that there is a fundamental world view difference between graphic software users and CAD users.

- CAD users think that the line is the base primitive
- Graphic software users think that the face is the base primitive

Often users on both camps lack the understanding that you can in fact use both in both cases and that ultimately it depends on you level of abstraction as to which you will choose. This reflects in the tools you see. Now unfortunately to you the simpler the software gets the less likely it is to understand this, and force the world view. In your case even worse. In 2d graphics land *trim* is a really advanced feature almost unheard of.*

Now the equivalent of **trim** in illustrator is **shape builder**. It is however primed to make faces by default. That's what most users are doing after all. But face priority becomes a boon when you realize you can color the areas between lines, in which case they need to be faces anyway.**

[image]

**Image 1:** How a illustrator user would approach your first image.

Now, I have created faces because I may want to color the surfaces later (see image 2). Though that may be a white lie, its easier to make faces than delete just lines, id have to click around and dragging lines is faster in this case. Unfortunately you may need to learn your workflow from scratch. It is painful to understand that what you take for granted isn't so self evident. Or just do it in autocad extort to PDF and open in illustrator if you feel learning something is beneath you.

[image]

**Image 2**: After filling image 2

* Trim requires more complex data structures and is generally nasty to make efficient in the software whereas just drawing shapes as you encounter them is built into the hardware. I can make a snapping line drawing tool in 20 lines of javascript. trimming efficiently requires 400-1000 more lines, and me to know a lot about a lot.

** Further there is a general BUG in all, but some very special experimental, vector graphics drawing engines. So users tend to avoid making perfectly fitting interlocking shapes becasue you can see trough the corners. See [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060) so it is natural for 2D graphics people to steer clear of this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Perfect answer.