# Blend to transparent doesn't work!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, illustrator-effects, blending

I'm trying to blend this world map into transparent. It works just fine with a rectangle. I also tried increasing or decreaing the steps and different blend options, nothing works..

[image]

Anyone how I can achieve this effect with this map?

Comment: Can just be a bad preview situation. What do you see if you save this as PDF or JPG ?

Comment: Yeah you're right!!! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet this is just a bad preview situation. Try to save this as PDF or JPG, it may actually look right on a finished export.

Comment: Its actually a aspect of the same problem as [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060), essentially super sampling has no conflation issues.