# Illustrator: Pixel perfect designs for video work

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel-grid

What are your tips and guidelines when designing stuff in Illustrator for video work? I currently do not use the pixel grid and I think that may be part of my problem. I mostly design stuff in Illustrator for use in After Effects. One thing I noticed is that when I import illustrator files there is a slight gap between the objects. Before importing, I made sure that every edge and anchor point is aligned properly in Illustrator. How do you use the pixel grid feature to design pixel-perfect designs so that there is no "in-between pixel" artifacts?

Comment: Two things: one, yes, use the pixel grid if you know your put is raster, and two, overlap your elements - the edge artifacts you get due to anti-aliasing will be an issue otherwise. Look at this Q/A set to get a better understanding: 
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg

Comment: Actually i think the pixel grid in illustrator is flawed. What you want is a grid that is 1/2 pixel in size. So just use a normal grid with those settings. Yeah theres inner and outer strokes to cover this.... BUT it does not account for you having need to draw non closed shapes. Yeah conflation artifacts are a problem You need to make sure objects overlap. But there is a alternative to that. And that is to not use the AA of illustrator but instead export without AA and then scale that down, you get better AA but obviously lose the benefits of preview and Aftereffects 3:rd best feature.

Comment: @joojaa everything I have been reading online is to keep everything in whole pixels. How would .5 pixels work in this case?

Comment: Same way. Whole pixel argument asumes you never draw lines