# How to delete spaces between different shapes after you divide a shape in multiple ones in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, graphic-styles

[image]I'm a beginner with adobe illustrator and for a project we need to split letters(A,B,C..) in many pieces because we need it for an application, and I did that using shape builder tool, pathfinder-divide, knife tool etc but when I save it as SVG(we need it like that) the shapes have a bit space in borders(like a white line). Does anybody know how can I divide without those lines or hide them?

Comment: Are you able to provide any visual examples? I think it would help to show of the issue more clearly

Comment: Sounds like conflation artefacts.  Could you please post a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: If these are conflation artefacts, see [possible related question here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060)

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, can you please check this image.

Comment: @epp Yes, those are conflation artefacts.

Answer (score 0):

SVGs with exact borders between parts have that error. It's not in SVGs. Programs which render those SVGs for raster displays create 1px wide partially transparent zone to reduce jagginess. That's anti-aliasing. You must put something behind the shapes, maybe the same shapes shifted 1px horizontally and vertically or generate overlaps by inserting a stroke.