# Draw strokes keeping same width

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to draw 10 circles between 1 and 2 (figure 1), keeping same width as the circles own stroke have (10 pt). But if I apply blend that produces some gaps (figure 2) which I do not want.

How can I draw 10 circles(each need to be 10 pt stroke width) between 1 and 2, and no gap will be there.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you blend in this case?

Comment: Joojaa what option do I have without applying blend? blend- steps- I applied this one.

Comment: I presume the strokes will be of various colors (or weights) after the blend is expanded...

Comment: @Scott yeah but why isnt that end resukt explained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to **start differently**....

- Draw the first circle
- Choose `Object > Path > Offset Path` and enter 110pts (10 strokes x 10pt + 10pt for half the stroke width on each the outer and inner circle = 110pts) to get the second, larger, circle.
- *Then* create the 10 step blend and there won't be any gaps.

[image]

**Note** the thin white lines you see are **not** gaps, they are [**conflation artifacts**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65060/3270) due to anti-aliasing and the strokes butting against each other.

---

To correct what's already drawn (Although I recommend just starting over)....

2 circles, 10pt stokes, blend between then 10 steps...

[image]

The gap appears because the distance *between* the two circles is **not** 100pts. (10pt stroke x 10 instances = 100pts total)

An easy solution is to use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow), hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and select the outer circle. Then switch to the **Free Transform Tool**, ensure `Scale Strokes and Effects` is **not** checked on the **Transform Panel**, and reduce the size of the outer circle (Holding Option/Alt and Shift) until the gaps are gone.

[image]

I expanded the blend to get the individual circles.

---

Comment: 21 seconds apart 

Comment: I was makin animations :)

Comment: am about to cry, no way I could make it, wasted hours :@. Thank you Scott <3

Comment: Just a little correction. In your second bullet you actually have to offset the path `10 strokes × 10 pt + 10 pt = 110 pt` because you have to take the strokes of the two existing circles into account.

Comment: Pretty sure. The way you do it fits with 9 inner circles. You just don't notice that the strokes you have made are actually overlapping. Try for example if you only want *one* single circle added. With your formula you get `1 stroke × 10 pt = 10 pt`, but then you just get two touching circles. You need to add 10 pt more.

Comment: Are you sure those gaps aren't just conflation artifacts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133251/discussion-between-wolff-and-scott).

Comment: @NeverLookBack check new values in the first part of this answer.. use 110pt offset, not 100pt. Wolff is correct.

Comment: @Scott I understand. I will add that.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using a step blend, it would be easy enough to do this with a 10pt grid, and snap to grid enabled.

Then you could just manually draw the circles with a 10pt stroke until you have enough. Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> as you click and drag the circles will constrain the aspect ratio to 1:1.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The gaps between strokes probably occur because the available distance *d* between the two circles isn't exactly `10 × 10 pt = 100 pt`.

[image]

If you want the strokes to be exactly 10 pt, you have to adjust the size of of either circle 1 or 2 so *d* becomes exactly 100 pt.

Alternatively, if you just want 10 strokes to fit within *d*, you must make the stroke width `d / 10`.

Comment: Client sends me the rough, and no changes can be made. am drawing exactly like his highness sent.  

:/ 

I will send him this. I wasted hours on it.

Comment: Thank you Wolff <3