# Best method to illustrate random shapes using the shapebuilder tool? Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, pen-tool

So I traced a series of shapes to give the impression of grocceries in a trolley. I first used the pen tool making intersecting lines and then using the shapebuilder tool filled with colour and removed overlapping paths.

I have encountered a problem however if I do want to tweak any shapes afterwards there are gaps. I guess Im starting to realise that the shapebuilder tool has a kind of cookie cutter effect. I am wondering if there is a better method of doing this with this particular random mosaic of shapes? Perhaps just creating individual shapes instead?
I think using the pen tool to create shapes with intersecting paths and then using the shapebuilder tool probably not the best method in this case.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

One creates *individual objects*, then merely stacks them on top of each other. There is no inherent problem with merely stacking objects. In fact, to avoid **[conflation artifacts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060)**, stacking can be preferable in many instances.

Shape Builder (and Live Paint) will indeed have a "cookie cutter" effect on artwork, *removing* objects underneath where the tool has been used.

[image]

(There's no simple or easy way to undo what Shape Builder/Live Paint does to shapes. Other than hitting "undo" repeatedly. They are *destructive* tools.)