# Issue with export from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, pdf, export

I wanted to export my work in PDF from illustrator, but I have a problem my lines of the flower are very visible I don't know how to do it for make it smooth. I don't know my be it's normal. you can help me. thank you

All my settings is high quality

[image]

Comment: If it happens that the obvious leak of the background white at the seams of differently colored areas annoy you, you have good chances to be the one who gets the prize of the 1000th complainer of the same effect. That's  common when the colored areas do not overlap, but have exactly fitting seams. Rendering them to a bitmap image for displays leaves 1...2 px wide partially transparent gap which is there to avoid jaggy borders. It's called "anti-aliasing". Have something less offensive than white behind the arty parts - maybe a rasterized copy or 1 px shifted copy or a well selected solid color

Comment: These are known as [conflation artifacts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060). Please read the duplicate.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is that an image trace?  If so, you can fix it by choosing the "overlapping" option in the advanced trace settings. [see here](https://imgur.com/dtqBegl)