# Remove unneeded lines from downloaded asset

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-editing, visual-artifacts

When I export the moon and stars group on the left side of [this asset](https://stock.adobe.com/images/ramadan-kareem-decoration-isolated-gold-shiny-glitter-glowing-crescent-islamic-with-stars-eid-mubarak/329305595) as PNG, I notice these thin white lines:

[image]

In Illustrator these lines are not as pronounced, but I see a hint of them, like here:

[image]

How can I remove these lines? I've ungrouped everything in the AI file, but I don't see a way to select these lines.

Comment: Thye should dissapear if you export them with a multisampling AA filter.

Comment: That worked! Feel free to post as an answer. The issue was never with a watermark as one commenter said

Comment: ive explained the effect [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060)

Comment: I see. In this case, though, the issue was surfacing in the output image.

Comment: Its probably run trough transparency flattener. it has a tendency to sliver up images like this.