# Inkscape. Is there a way of disabling the thin line when using division(without turning off anti-alliasing)?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, anti-aliasing

Just take for example simple rectangle that I split with division. When I use division there is always this thin line that shows where the division is.
[image]
I thought it's only an issue in the program itself, but it's also noticeable in the exported SVG. Except, if I turn off the anti-aliasing. This thing doesn't happen in Illustrator even when the anti-aliasing is on.

Edit: It's actually happening in Illustrator too but it's less noticeable.

Comment: These are conflation artifacts caused by two vector shapes butting up against each other. It's a common problem with vector image editors, not just Inkscape. [see possible duplicate here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46353/get-rid-of-thin-white-lines-between-shape-joins). Avoid doing that. Merge/unite the shapes, or add a thin stroke same colour as the fill so there's a slight overlap.

Comment: Another similar question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82139/how-to-get-rid-of-lines-between-vector-shapes-in-sketch-3), and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64885/white-lines-not-strokes-appearing-between-shapes-after-using-pathfinder-tool)

Comment: I also found another similar question, so I'm closing this as a duplicate.